# Show custom alert on window

Tags: ios, ipad

I have my custom alert in my ios application.that i am adding on a view controller and it works fine.

But now in one situation my view get hide below one view so now i need to add on parent view means on above all view or window.

what is the best way

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
[parentview bringSubviewToFront:alertview]

Answer (score 0):

Directly add on application window

```
[self.view.window addSubview: myView];
```

Hope this will work for you.